# Flutter Container unwanted top and bottom padding

Tags: android, flutter, dart, containers, padding

I created a Container with red color as background, and another one with white color as its child.
I think the red one will be fully covered by the white one. Instead, I see two red lines on top and bottom of the container. Its like the Container has top and bottom padding, and I can't remove it.

How to remove it (the top and bottom padding?) so that the white fully cover the red one?

[The red line shows like the container has top and bottom padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj1Ep.jpg)

update:
Just tested it on a new project, and it shows perfectly, no padding.
Any idea what causing this?

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test(Object args);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ContainerTest();
  }
}

class ContainerTest extends State<Test>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("some text"),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("some text"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be fine there is no issue you see the red lines on top and bottom due to the **small size** of **simulator/emulator**

> Please increase the size or check in the Real Device it will be fine

[image]

Comment: the lines also visible on my redmi note 5

Comment: Just tested it on a new project, and it shows perfectly, no padding. Any idea what causing this?

Comment: @aryono there is no issue If solving your problem please accept and upvote the answer.